# datagridview Insert Image dynamic #2

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [datagridview dynamic with image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803090/datagridview-dynamic-with-image)

He liked to give me a help to create a datagridview dynamically. C # WindowsForms

The objective is to ping a list of IP or HostName's success and if inserted in the grid (host, date, and Image Red or Green) depending on response.

I have this function that writes the grid, but I have a problem if one ping is not successful he puts all others with `Redball`.

```
private void TabelaDinamimca(bool sucesso,string host, string data)
{
    GridView1.ColumnCount = 3;

    GridView1.Columns[1].Name = "host";
    GridView1.Columns[2].Name = "data";
    DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    string path = (sucesso == true 
                  ? @"C:\TestFolder\greenBall.png" 
                  : @"C:\TestFolder\redBall.png");
    Image image = Image.FromFile(path);
    img.Image = image;
    GridView1.Columns.Add(img);
    string[] row = new string[] { host, data };
    GridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    GridView1.Show();
}
```

NOTE: In debug mode the bool sucesso case `Erro` is false

SOLUTION

```
private void TabelaDinamimcaSucess(bool sucesso, int index, string host, string data, string tempo,string status)
    {

       string[] row = new string[] { index.ToString(), host, data, tempo,status };
       dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

        int number_of_rows = dataGridView1.RowCount -1;

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap((sucesso == true ? Properties.Resources.greenBall : Properties.Resources.redBall));
        Icon icon = Icon.FromHandle(b.GetHicon());

        dataGridView1.Rows[number_of_rows].Cells["img"].Value = icon;

        dataGridView1.Show();
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is this your real code ? It looks like you're adding the image colum at each call of this method... also, I think the the problem is that you're setting the image to the column and not in the cell value...

Comment: i think the problem is the insert picture column

I think the problem is in me being put in the column and not in the cell

thank you

when you have the resolution and put it here

Comment: Sounds and awful like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803090/datagridview-dynamic-with-image/13803649#13803649 What coincidence! Same class names and everything.

Comment: @JohnSaunders um all the words in the title are tags and removing the C# tag doesn't really help. Perhaps it should have been edited to something helpful like *How do you display different images dynamically in a DataGridView instead of repeating the same image?*

Comment: @ConradFrix: go right ahead and edit the title.