# datagridview dynamic with image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need a little help to create a datagridview dynamically.

The objective is to ping a list of IP or HostName's success and inserted in the grid (host, date, and Image (Red or Green)) depending on response.

I have this function that writes the grid, but I have a problem if one ping is not successful he puts all others with Redball.

Heres the code i'm using http://codepaste.net/yq1pu9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  private void TabelaDinamimcaSucess(bool sucesso, int index, string host, string data, string tempo,string status)
{

   string[] row = new string[] { index.ToString(), host, data, tempo,status };
   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

    int number_of_rows = dataGridView1.RowCount -1;

    Bitmap b = new Bitmap((sucesso == true ? Properties.Resources.greenBall : Properties.Resources.redBall));
    Icon icon = Icon.FromHandle(b.GetHicon());

    dataGridView1.Rows[number_of_rows].Cells["img"].Value = icon;

    dataGridView1.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you uncomment all the `GridView1.Rows.Add` lines for testing purposes?

I noticed that in all three blocks where you add rows to your `DataGridView`, you're always sending `GridView1.Rows.Add(`**pictureRed**`, TextboxHost.Text, TextboxWhen.Text);`

Did you mean to have something like `GridView1.Rows.Add(`**pictureGreen**`, TextboxHost.Text, TextboxWhen.Text);` under your `if (Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)` block?